# typescript class constructor infer type from constructor arguments

Tags: node.js, typescript

Let's say I have a class like this one :

```
class Entity {
  id?: string;
  name?: string;
  constructor({ id, name }: { id?: string; name?: string }) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

And then I have a function like this which requires an argument of type Entity but with the id property field set:

```
function myFunc(entity: Entity & { id: string }) {
  console.log("do something", entity.id);
}
```

I would expect the following to work, but it doesn't:

```
const myEntityWithoutID = new Entity({ name: "no id" });

const myEntityWithID = new Entity({ name: "dummy", id: "dummy" });

myFunc(myEntityWithoutID); // error, as expected

myFunc(myEntityWithID); // error, but this should work
```

I'm not sure how I can force typescript to correctly infer the type of the class instance. I hope I've given enough information in order to present the problem, does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: I don't believe this is a supported use case. Typescript cannot dynamically figure out what type of `Entity` you've created. It just knows that an `Entity` was created, and from how the class is defined, it knows that both `id` and `name` are optional.